# Title of the window appears in the body when use display: inline; in the universal * selector

Tags: html, css

Look a this code:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>This is a title </title>

    <style>
        
        *{
            display: inline;
        }
        
        title{
            background: #F24A72;
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            height: 22px;
            text-align: center;
            color: azure;
            font-size: 15px;
        }

    </style>
    
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Now try to render this in your browser. I'm searching the reason of why the title appears in the body and the css code too.

Comment: Please look into this: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Never ever make all the elements inline. You simply broke everything, don't try to understand a broken thing

Comment: You changed `head`, `title`, and `style` to `display: inline`. Why would you expect the title text to *not* be displayed given your explicit instruction?